# Менять картинку на странице товара при клике на цвет WooCommerce

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Как можно сделать без использования плагинов, чтобы при клике на цвет менялась картинка товара? Существует ли какой-то способ связать цвета и вариативные картинки и вывести их в одном цикле?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все это находится в `single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php`

Comment: Это делается js-кодом. Без вашей html-разметки, приведённой в вопросе, помочь вам невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="color-selection size-1">
    <div data-slug="blue" class="entry" style="color: #3481c7;"></div>
    <div data-slug="gray" class="entry" style="color: #eeeeee;"></div>
    <div data-slug="yellow" class="entry" style="color: #edb82c;"></div>
    <input id="pa_color" type="hidden" class="color_val" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_color"
           name="attribute_pa_color" value="light-blue">
</div>

Все это находитсяв в single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php
```

Answer (score 0):

C woocomerce не работал но примерно так вы сможете зацепится к цвету, немного поправьте под себя или покажите относительные пути к картинкам товара, и разметку товара

```
$('[data-slug]').on("click", function() {
    slug = $(this).data("slug");
    $('#imageContainer').attr("src", "/img/products/product-slug.png");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

То что выше предложено (JS или CSS ), это огород и дурдом, но не решение! Для решения есть плагины. Например: - Improved Product Options for WooCommerce от XforWooCommerce и Improved Variable Product Attributes for WooCommerce от Mihajlovic Nenad. Вероятно есть и другие, но меня устраивают эти. Повторюсь, что бы подменялись картинки, не помогут костыли, надо писать плагин или использовать имеющиеся.